# Polymer 2.0 Edge Issue

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

Using Polymer 2.0, I wrote an app whose entry point is a page in a CMS.  The page loads the polyfills, imports the app's entry point, and puts the custom element into the page.  This process works well in Chrome and Firefox; in Edge, however, there is a problem.  I'm getting errors like this in the JavaScript console:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'PropertyEffects'

Unable to get property '__mixinSet' of undefined or null reference

Function is not a constructor
```

The app is using the regular, unbuilt source code.  How can these errors be interpreted or resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Version of Edge do you use?

Note from polymer serve source (https://github.com/Polymer/polyserve/blob/master/src/compile-middleware.ts#L150)

```
// Note: The Edge user agent uses the EdgeHTML version, not the main
// release version (e.g. EdgeHTML 15 corresponds to Edge 40). See
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Release_history.
//
// Versions before 15.15063 may contain a JIT bug affecting ES6
// constructors (see #161).
```

So for Edge up to this version you still need to provide an alternative ES5 Version.

If you are using `polymer serve` it will transpile your ES6 to ES5 on the fly if needed.

For everything else you should use `polymer build` to provide ES5 code. Which you then serve if needed. (check on server via user agent string)